# Creating a shared library from list of static libraries

Tags: gcc, g++, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Hi I am trying to creating a so file from list of object files and .a files. But i am getting errors. Here is the below command and error.

```
 gcc -g -shared bucomm.o filemode.o libiberty.a version.o make-temp-file.o  -o liballshared.so

make-temp-file.o: In function `choose_tmpdir':
/home/dinesh/packages/binutils-2.29/libiberty/./make-temp-file.c:106: multiple definition of `choose_tmpdir'
libiberty.a(make-temp-file.o):/home/dinesh/packages/binutils-2.29/libiberty/./make-temp-file.c:106: first defined here
make-temp-file.o: In function `make_temp_file':
/home/dinesh/packages/binutils-2.29/libiberty/./make-temp-file.c:185: multiple definition of `make_temp_file'
libiberty.a(make-temp-file.o):/home/dinesh/packages/binutils-2.29/libiberty/./make-temp-file.c:185: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Sooooo... What do you expect? It's telling you some of your objects have conflicting definitions for some functions.

Comment: i removed libiberty.a from the command and it compiled. I am not able figure out what the issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not able figure out what the issue is

Here:

```
make-temp-file.o: In function `choose_tmpdir':
/home/dinesh/packages/binutils-2.29/libiberty/./make-temp-file.c:106: multiple definition of `choose_tmpdir'
```

the linker tells you that the object file `make-temp-file.o` defines a function `choose_tmpdir` that
has already been defined in an object file that has already been linked. The linker doesn't allow
you to link multiple definitions of `choose_tmpdir`. Which definition is it supposed to link in your `liballshared.so`?

Next:

```
libiberty.a(make-temp-file.o):/home/dinesh/packages/binutils-2.29/libiberty/./make-temp-file.c:106: first defined here
```

the linker tells you that the object file `make-temp-file.o` in the static library `libiberty.a` is the object file it has
already linked in which `choose_tmpdir` was already defined.

Next:

```
make-temp-file.o: In function `make_temp_file':
/home/dinesh/packages/binutils-2.29/libiberty/./make-temp-file.c:185: multiple definition of `make_temp_file'
libiberty.a(make-temp-file.o):/home/dinesh/packages/binutils-2.29/libiberty/./make-temp-file.c:185: first defined here
```

the linker tells you that you also have a multiple definition of function `make_temp_file`, which is also
defined in `make-temp-file.o` and which has also already been defined when `make-temp-file.o` was previously linked
from within the static library `libiberty.a`.

Both of these multiple definition errors occur because in your linkage command:

```
gcc -g -shared bucomm.o filemode.o libiberty.a version.o make-temp-file.o  -o liballshared.so
```

you first give the linker the library `libiberty.a`, which contains the object file `make-temp-file.o`,
and then you give the linker `make-temp-file.o` again.

When you give the linker an object file, it links it unconditionally in your program or shared libarary. When you give
the linker a static library, it inspects the object files in the static library, extracts only the ones
that it needs and links them in your program or shared library. The linker *needs* an object file from a static library
if that object file provides a definition for one or more symbols that have been referred to, but not
yet defined, in object files that it has already linked.

When the linker gets to `libiberty.a` in your commandline, it inspects
the object files in the library to see if any of them provide definitions for undefined symbols
referred to in the object files it has already linked into your `liballshared.so` (namely `bucomm.o` and `filemode.o`).
It discovers that `libiberty.a(make-temp-file.o)` provides definitions for functions `choose_tmpdir` and
`make_temp_file`, which it needs. So it extracts `make-temp-file.o` from `libiberty.a` and links it in your shared library.

When it gets to `make-temp-file.o` in your commandline, it links it unconditionally. So this object file has
now been linked twice in your shared library, and the symbols that it defines have been defined twice in your shared library,
so your linkage fails.

Your linkage will *not* fail with the command:

```
gcc -g -shared bucomm.o filemode.o version.o make-temp-file.o libiberty.a -o liballshared.so
```

in which `libiberty.a` comes after all the object files. All of the object files will be linked,
unconditionally, before `libiberty.a` is inspected. And when `libiberty.a` is inspected, the linker
will *not* extract and link `libiberty.a(make-temp-file.o)` because *it is not needed*.

Moral: *Link object files first, libraries afterwards*.

You comment that your linkage succeeds if you remove `libiberty.a` altogether. If that is true, it
tells you that *all* symbols referred to in your shared library are defined in one of `bucomm.o filemode.o version.o make-temp-file.o`,
so there was no point in linking `libiberty.a` to begin with. But if you stick to the rule of
linking object files first, libraries afterwards, then no harm will be done by having libraries
in the linkage that aren't needed. Libraries that are not needed will add nothing to the program
or shared library you are linking.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its a very clear explanation. Helped me a lot.

Comment: @DineshGowda Welcome to Stackoverflow! You might like to read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)